# Brightness control in FreeBSD 10.3 RELEASE on Dell XPS L702X

Tags: freebsd, nvidia-geforce, brightness, dell-xps

I am trying to change the screen brightness.

I've already tried:

- Loading `acpi_video` with `kldload`.

  The module loads fine however `sysctl hw.acpi.video` prints only:

  > sysctl: unknown oid 'hw.acpi.video'
- Adding `Option      "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"` to the `Device` section. It doesn't work. Rebooting didn't help.
- Running `xbacklight(1)`.
- Installing `nvidia-settings`. It seems like I cannot control the brightness from there.

---

### Details

- `uname -a` returns:

  > FreeBSD pc 10.3-RELEASE-p4 FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE-p4 #0: Sat May 28 12:23:44 UTC 2016     root@amd64-builder.daemonology.net:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
- The machine is Dell XPS L702X.
- The graphic card is NVIDIA GT550M.
- I use an external Samsung 2043NW display.

#### Related threads

- [How to adjust brightness screen? (The FreeBSD Forums)](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/6186/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to use `xbacklight(1)` and activate the brightness control keys but I've found a couple of other ways to change the brightness:

1. ### `xrandr(1)`

   Thanks to *[How to change LCD intensivity/brightness](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61265/128489)* I was able to change the brightness of the external monitor using `xrandr`. The command looks like this:

   ```
   xrandr --output HDMI-0 --brightness 0.9
   ```

   The default value seems to be `1`.
2. ### `redshift(1)`

   Redshift is a software allowing you to change the temperature of your screen. It has `-b`, `-t` and `-g` options which might come handy (see `man redshift` for more details).

One way or another, I would still like to know if it is possible to use `xbacklight` on this machine.

---

> It looks like the problem with colors might be caused by the fact that I connect the monitor over a VGA-HDMI adapter. HDMI seem to mess up the colors of a connected monitor this way.

I've found a solution to this problem: *[Yellow and gray blend with white on a remote monitor connected with a HDMI-VGA adapter](https://superuser.com/a/1214435/442991)*