# How to change brightness in FreeBSD?

Tags: xorg, amd-radeon, freebsd, brightness, vesa

I installed FreeBSD 10.3 stable on my HP laptop and installed Mate desktop, but I can not change laptop's brightness.

I used `xrandr`, `xbacklight`, `redshift` and they did not work. I loaded `acpi_video` too, but it has not `hw.apic.video`.

Is there a way to change brightness?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Brightness control in FreeBSD 10.3 RELEASE on Dell XPS L702X](https://superuser.com/questions/1124755/brightness-control-in-freebsd-10-3-release-on-dell-xps-l702x)

Comment: Also, you might find this one useful: [Is there a way to reduce screen brightness or change its colors when using the SCFB driver on FreeBSD?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/370492/128489)

Comment: Also, here are my notes on setting up video drivers (it is for Lenovo Yoga 3 14 but you might find it useful): https://wiki.freebsd.org/MateuszPiotrowski/Yoga314/X

Comment: But if you have to use VESA or SCFB as a driver then you are probably out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

In FreeBSD 13 the `backlight(8)` utility was introduced.

```
backlight -f /dev/backlight/backlight0 10
```

Answer (score 1):

On FreeBSD 12.1 and ThinkPad I have `sysctl hw.acpi.video.lcd0.brightness`